# CSS in VS-Code: why is the property "cursor" highlighted in yellow while all other correctly-spelled properties are highlighted in blue?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass, syntax, codehighlighter

I was wondering, when writing CSS in VS-Code: why is the property "cursor" highlighted in yellow, while all other properties are highlighted in blue?

[image]

I appreciate any insight.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is a bad bug.  If you check `cursor` scope it shows that it is a tag, specifically `entity.name.tag.css`!  I bet that same yellow is used for your real tags.

You can work around it with this in your settings:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {

     "textMateRules": [
       {
         "scope": "meta.property-list.scss entity.name.tag.css",
         "settings": {
           "foreground": "#f3873f",   // set to whatever color your tags are
                                      // which the same "Tokens and Scopes" Inspector
                                      // in the command palette will show you
         }
       },
     ]
},
```

You should file the bug with vscode issues.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Comment: Just looked for the issue in the vs code repo. The bug was filed [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/114466) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/48295) but the [fix](https://github.com/atom/language-sass/issues/226) seems to be in eternal limbo.